# Can a taxonomy term be loaded into an EntityMetadataWrapper?

Tags: entities

I want to load term fields in my application. Can I use  entity metadata wrapper with reference to terms?

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Like so:

```
$term_w = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', taxonomy_term_load(TERM_ID));
```

The first parameter is the entity type ID. If you visit MODULE_NAME_entity_info(), you can see the key of the definition will match the ID you need to load it.

Comment: If i used $term_w = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', taxonomy_term_load(TERM_ID));  its giving me error saying that property its not define.  e.g $term_w->field_test->value()

Comment: That worked for me, though.  Try `$term_w->getPropertyInfo()` to see what properties are defined.

Answer (score 10):

Sam152 is right, but you don't actually need to convert the term_id to an object, it will work with just the term_id being passed as is:

```
$term_w = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', TERM_ID);
```